# Jupyter Cassandra Save Problem - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder

Tags: python, csv, cassandra, pyspark, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook and want to save csv file to cassandra db. There is no problem while getting data and showing it, But when I try to save this csv data to cassandra db it throws below exception.

```
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder
```

I dowloaded maven package manually both 2.4.0 and 2.4.1 and none of them worked. Also stated packages at the top of code.

```
import sys
import uuid
import time
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0 pyspark-shell'

try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from itertools import islice
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    from datetime import datetime

except ImportError as e:
    print("error importing spark modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Stand Alone Python Script").setMaster("local[*]")\
                        .setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '8g'),\
                        ('spark.executor.cores', '3'),\
                        ('spark.cores.max', '3'),\
                        ('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'cassandra_ip'),\
                        ('spark.cassandra.auth.username', 'cassandra_user_name'),\
                        ('spark.cassandra.auth.password', 'cassandra_password'),\
                        ('spark.driver.memory','8g')])

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)



consumer_complaints = sql_context.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "false").load("in/Consumer_Complaints.csv")
consumer_complaints.write\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .mode('append')\
    .options(table="table_name", keyspace="space_name")\
    .save()


sc.stop()
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it in the `pyspark`, without Jupyter? Can you try to use `datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.4.1-s_2.11` in the `--packages` option instead of `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0`

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes I used both way. Also defined --jar but not worked any of them

Comment: strange - the `datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.4.1-s_2.11` should be a fat jar, with all dependencies...

Comment: @AlexOtt it's only shaded for some DSE libs, but --packages should download all dependencies as well. So i'm guessing the syntax above was just not getting applied correctly :/

Comment: For both variants worked just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I solved my problem with following steps:

downloaded twitter jsr jar and moved it to $SPARK_HOME/jars directory.

```
cp /home/jovyan/.m2/repository/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar /usr/local/spark/jars/
```

Also because of docker's jupyter user is jovyan not root I grant permission to this folder

I used directly below statement but you can use more restrictive way.

```
chmod -R 777 /usr/local/spark/jars/
```

Thank you