# Pyspark : Writing data frame into Cassandra table is not working

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

When I tried to read the data from Cassandra table through pyspark is working fine. But when I tried to writing the Dataframe into Cassandra table is giving the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with same Spark-Cassandra connecting packages.

Versions Details :

Cassandra :

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.18 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
```

Spark :

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019 14:33:56)
```

Spark - Cassandra Connector :

```
bin/pyspark --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.4.0-s_2.11
```

Code:

```
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
>>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> import os
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder \
...   .appName('SparkCassandraApp') \
...   .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', '127.0.0.1') \
...   .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
...   .config('spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level','ONE') \
...   .master('local[2]') \
...   .getOrCreate()
>>> df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="emp",keyspace="tutorialspoint").load()
>>> df.show()
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
|emp_id| emp_city|emp_name| emp_phone|emp_sal|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
|     2|Hyderabad|   robin|9848022339|  40000|
|     1|Hyderabad|     ram|9848022338|  50000|
|     3|  Chennai|  rahman|9848022330|  45000|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+
```

In same terminal  trying to write into Cassandra table

```
>>> df.write\
... .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
... .mode('append')\
... .options(table="emp", keyspace="tutorialspoint")\
... .save()

19/09/26 15:34:15 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 6.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 25)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$TaskMetricsSupport$class.$init$(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$TaskMetricsUpdater.<init>(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$.apply(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:75)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:209)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:197)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:183)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/09/26 15:34:15 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 26)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$TaskMetricsSupport$class.$init$(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$TaskMetricsUpdater.<init>(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$.apply(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:75)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:209)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:197)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:183)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did my solution help?

Answer (score 0):

You need a different `cassandra-connector`. The Datastax connector would work for Scala/Java but you need something for a python counterpart.

[arguenot/pyspark-cassandra](https://github.com/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra) is a Python port of the Datastax Spark Connector.

Example:

```
import pyspark_cassandra

conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("PySpark Cassandra Test") \
    .setMaster("spark://spark-master:7077") \
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cas-1")

sc = CassandraSparkContext(conf=conf)

rdd = sc.parallelize([{
    "key": k,
    "stamp": datetime.now(),
    "val": random() * 10,
    "tags": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "options": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": "qux",
    }
} for k in ["x", "y", "z"]])

rdd.saveToCassandra(
    "keyspace",
    "table",
    ttl=timedelta(hours=1),
)
```

Comment: Datastax connector should work just fine with Python: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md

Comment: @AlexOtt I recently had a `not working as expected` experience. Have you tried it out? I will try and update my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened with me as well, something has probably gone wrong with the standard --packages for the connector. The jsr long adder jar is missing and/or replaced with a different one that isn't recognized by pyspark somewhere. If you download the missing jar and include it as another --package it will work.

Solution derived from the following answer

> [Jupyter Cassandra Save Problem - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276840/jupyter-cassandra-save-problem-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-twitter-jsr)